# Qt Quick controls 2.0 for embedded device

Tags: c++, qt, optimization, qtquick2, qtquickcontrols2

My long term goal is to make HCI development for embedded devices, and by embedded I really mean it, not phone devices.

I've been working on Qt Widgets for a month now, avoiding Qt Quick for some reasons (I feared that QML code wasn't optimize), but yesterday I have watched this video :[Youtube](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=WIRRoPxIerc&feature=youtu.be) 
The speaker says at the end : "If you're making an embedded product these days, use Qt Quick, especially now in 5.8. There's no excuse not to use Qt Quick"

But on the contrary, he explains that for embedded devices we should use c++ code, not JavaScript.

I don't really get it, does it means that I have to create all my objects in c++ code and make my architecture using Qt Quick ?

I don't really get what Qt want us to do. Is it just communication, since they don't want to optimize the old and stable Qt widgets, or is Qt Quick really the solution for embedded devices ?

I personally think that Qt is not the solution for embedded devices, as they keep evolving, changing strategy, and seems not to know where they are going.

I apologize for this non-algorithmic question, and thank you for all your answers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can't speak to the developer's intent, nor can I speak for other developers. I can only speak to what I understand, as a developer that has been designing embedded devices for 40 years (sorry for being a number dropper).

C++ or JavaScript? I don't feel that question has too much to do with whether you use QtQuick or not. Sure, you can embed some JaveScript in QML code (with limitations), but you can also use C++ in the same code base (just not embedded in the QML). Then there's Python. Both Qt and QtQuick are programming frameworks, and are somewhat language agnostic.

My perspective is that QtQuick is a good, portable way to create your user-interface code. In my current project (a multi-axis industrial servo-control system) I use QML for the user-interface (with a little JavaScript where needed), C++ for the bulk of the higher level processing (like network control and data-streaming), C and assembly language for the lower levels (those routines executed in uC's and DSP's). QML and C++ interface together nicely, in my opinion.

Comment: As you are an experimented designer for embedded devices, I guess you used for some previous application Flash ? I try to compare both "Frameworks" for (only only for this right now) the design part.
As my expert assessment is (very) low on Qt, your comment encourage me going further in my researches. Thank you

Comment: I haven't used Flash for a user-interface before, as I have never used HTTP for communications. Until the 90's, user interfaces were simply push-buttons and sometimes a character-based LCD. Then, as more sophisticated UI's were needed, I added programmable terminals or used C# with Visual Studio. I've been using Qt for only the past few years.

Answer (score 1):

I believe the speaker is getting at the idea that most if not all your business logic should be done using a C++ model back-end. It is possible to do all your logic just in QML with embedded JavaScript however, because JS is an interpreted language its performance at run-time can possibly be less than compiled C++ code(dependent on how well the C++ is written).

Essentially you only want to use JS to manipulate graphical components while using C++ with QObject models to update the QtQuick elements' individual properties.

This is mentioned in the Qt Quick Best Practices wiki,
https://wiki.qt.io/Qt_Quick_Best_Practices